# How to assign command line argument parameters to programs run by gem5 in syscall emulation?

Tags: gem5

The programs run with gem5 before are all without parameters. But what should I do if the program I am running requires parameters. I tried `--cmd="add 3 4"`， which is not work. I am currently trying to run `Coremark` with gem5. The command to run Coremark directly is `./coremark.exe 0x0 0x0 0x66 0 7 1 2000> ./run1.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass command line parameters with `--options` as in:

```
gem5.opt configs/example/se.py --cmd add --options '3 4'
```