# Passing command line arguments to binary in gem5

Tags: gem5

I am trying to pass command line arguments to a binary that I am simulating on gem5. I want to simulate the following:

```
./binary 1
```

I have tried:

```
gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py binary 1
gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py binary --options '1'
gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py --cmd binary --options '1'
```

Which are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593440/how-to-assign-command-line-argument-parameters-to-programs-run-by-gem5-in-syscal) and [here](http://old.gem5.org/Running_gem5.html) but seem to be depreciated. Nearly all of these give `error: unrecognized arguments: -options 1` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last command in your question:

`gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py --cmd binary --options '1'`

is almost correct. You just need to modify it a little:

`gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py --cmd=/path/to/binary --options="1 2 3"`

`--options` flag always needs "" for your arguments, and unless the binary is in the relative path it is always recommended to give the absolute path.

Another way to format the same would be:

`gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py -c /path/to/binary -o "1 2 3"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately this syntax gives the same results. I believe the issue lies in the two_level.py configuration which needs to be configured to take command line arguments which I am still looking into.

Comment: Yes that could very well be the case. Ysk that if you want to run any binary of your choice in a Syscall Emulation mode you can always run it using the configs/example/se.py file. This one is the default file and can easily get you started.